# How can I only allow setting a field in directus, if another field is empty?

Tags: content-management-system, directus

In my Directus collection called `link`, I have two fields: `page` and `url`.
Only on at a time should be set.

I added a condition to the `url` field and set it to "Page is null". I did the same for `page`, where I set the rule to "Url is null".

[image]

But it doesn't do anything, creating a `link` while setting both `url` and `page` still works.